# How can we determine a program is already running in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want run a program(exe) from my delphi application. i can do it, but i want to check whether program is already running or not before run it. Is there any way to do it.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Enumerating all Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Is that program yours?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why nobody voted to close as a duplicate? This is an extremely common question...

Comment: Feel free to link to the duplicate, @Jerry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function checks whether a process is running. Add "TlHelp32" to the uses clause.

```
function ProcessRunning (sExeName: String) : Boolean;
{ -> sExeName : Name of the EXE without path. Does not have to be the full EXE name. }

var
    hSnapShot : THandle;
    ProcessEntry32 : TProcessEntry32;

begin
    Result := false;

    hSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    Win32Check (hSnapShot <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    sExeName := LowerCase (sExeName);

    FillChar (ProcessEntry32, SizeOf (TProcessEntry32), #0);
    ProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf (TProcessEntry32);

    if (Process32First (hSnapShot, ProcessEntry32)) then
        repeat
            if (Pos (sExeName,
                     LowerCase (ProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) = 1) then
            begin
                Result := true;
                Break;
            end; { if }
        until (Process32Next (hSnapShot, ProcessEntry32) = false);

    CloseHandle (hSnapShot);
end; { ProcessRunning }
```

Comment: That is what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: This might seem like what you want but I doubt it. Using this, you can still start your process multiple times depending on timing. What you really need is a solution using a mutex. That said, this is still a handy function.

Comment: If you call this function before starting the process, @Lieven, and it returns true, you wouldn't start the process again. What does timing have to do with it? Are you assuming the goal is for the program to detect a previous instance of *itself*? There's been no indication that that's the goal.

Comment: Olaf, can you please explain the significance of the `Pos` call? Are there any possible inputs where `Pos` might yield the wrong answer for this function? Does the path to the file matter?

Comment: @RobKennedy - Using this solution, you can still start multiple instances of the process. Looking at the question, to me it looks like that's exactly what OP is trying to avoid. If my interpretation is wrong, OP, can correct me offcourse.

Comment: @Lieven, I'm imagining code like this: `if not ProcessRunning('foo') then RunProcess('foo')`. How will that start multiple instances of foo? It would *allow* multiple instances of foo, but only if the user starts foo multiple times, which is beyond the control of the Delphi program we're talking about writing today.

Comment: @RobKennedy - ah, now I understand our misunderstanding :). I'm indeed talking about the code still allowing multiple instances of foo and I indeed interpreted the question as OP likes to only ever have one instance of foo running. Coming to think of it: what does that code prevent if that's *not* the intention to begin with? It *doesn't* allow multiple instances after the first process is completely initialized but there's a small window of time where it does.